# Minimum value of a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

> Prove that the minimum value of $$a \sec \theta + b \csc \theta$$ is $$(a^{2/3} + b^{2/3})^{3/2}$$ where $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers.

This is one part of a larger question whose first part I solved. I tried to express $a \sec \theta + b \csc \theta$ in a more concise manner, but couldn't do so without introducing more variables.

Even after equating the function to the minimum, it is not clear to me how to find the value of $\theta$ for which the function attains its minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(\theta)=a\sec\theta+b\csc\theta,\quad 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$f'(\theta) = a\cdot(-1)\cdot(-\sin\theta)\cdot\sec^2\theta+b\cdot(-1)\cdot(\cos\theta)\cdot\csc^2\theta$

$$f'(\theta)= \frac{a\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta} -\frac{b\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$$

Setting $f'(\theta)=0:$

$$f'(\theta) = \frac{a\sin^3\theta-b\cos^3\theta}{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}=0$$

$$\implies a\sin^3\theta=b\cos^3\theta \implies \tan^3\theta=\frac{b}{a}\implies \tan\theta=\bigg(\frac{b}{a}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Then $\cos\theta = \frac{a^{1/3}}{\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}}\quad$ and $\sin\theta = \frac{b^{1/3}}{\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}}$

Then $f(\theta) = a\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}}{a^{1/3}}+b\cdot\frac{\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}}{b^{1/3}} =(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3})\cdot \sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}} = (a^{2/3}+b^{2/3})^{3/2}$

I leave it to you to show that the point is a minimum

Comment: How do you get the denominator in $\cos\theta = \frac{a^{1/3}}{\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}}\quad$ and $\sin\theta = \frac{b^{1/3}}{\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}}$?

Comment: @Airdish You use Pythagoras. We have that $\tan\theta = \frac{b^{1/3}}{a^{1/3}} =\frac{opposite}{adjacent}$. So then construct a right angled triangle, and calculate the hypotenuse to be $\sqrt{a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}}$, then you can easily calculate $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$

Comment: The fact that this is the minimum could be concluded from the second derivative and the fact that there is only one stationary point in the given interval, right?

Comment: @Airdish Yes that's correct

Answer (score 4):

By Holder's Inequality $(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta)(a \sec \theta+b \csc \theta)(a \sec \theta+b \csc \theta) \ge (a^{\frac{2}{3}}+b^{\frac{2}{3}})^3$

from which it follows that $a \sec \theta+b \csc \theta \ge (a^{\frac{2}{3}}+b^{\frac{2}{3}})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

let $$f(\theta)=\frac{a}{\cos(\theta)}+\frac{b}{\sin(\theta)}$$ then the first derivative is given by
$$f'(\theta)=a\frac{(
\sin(\theta))}{\cos(\theta)^2}-b\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)^2}$$
then you must solve the equation $$f'(\theta)=0$$ for $\theta$.

Comment: why that? i have used the Quotient rule

Comment: ok you have right it must be the opposite sign, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another equivalent approach is to consider $x= \cos \theta$ and $y = \cos \theta$ which lie on the unit circle.
This means you have the minimize the function: $$f(x,y) = \frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}$$
with the constraint $$x^2+y^2=1$$
for $x,y >0$. Lagrange multipliers will do the rest.

Answer (score -2):

If calculus is not mandatory,

as $a,b,\sec\theta,\csc\theta>0$

$$\dfrac{a\sec\theta+b\csc\theta}2\ge\sqrt{a\sec\theta\cdot b\csc\theta}$$

The equality occurs if $a\sec\theta=b\csc\theta$

$\iff\dfrac a{\cos\theta}=\dfrac b{\sin\theta}=+\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}1$  $'+'$ as $0<\theta<\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\sec\theta=\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}a$ and $\csc\theta=?$

Comment: I'm trying figure out why this method resulted in a wrong result.

Comment: The right-hand side is not a constant.

Comment: I look forward to seeing if this solution works out. A non-calculus solution would be very interesting indeed. I also thought initially of applying AM-GM but couldn't see it through...