# Find the minimum of $2/\sin(x)+3/\cos(x)$ using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I want to find the minimum of $f(x)=\dfrac{2}{\sin(x)}+\dfrac{3}{\cos(x)}$ when $0<x<\pi/2$ using the C-S inequality.

By using derivatives it is easy to show that the minimum is

$$(2^{2/3}+3^{2/3})^{3/2}$$

but i have no idea how to prove this using C-S ineq,my attempts ends with an inequality of opposite direction.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2252612/42969

Comment: Could comments please stop linking to proofs that _don't_ use CS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem** Let $a,\,b>0$. For $x\in(0,\,\pi/2)$, $(a^3\csc x+b^3\sec x)^2\ge(a^2+b^2)^3$, with equality iff $\tan x=a/b$.

**Comment** The present problem is $a=2^{1/3},\,b=3^{1/3}$.

**Proof by Cauchy-Schwarz** Use $u^2\ge\frac{(u\cdot v)^2}{v^2}$ with$$u=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a^{3/2}\csc^{1/2}x\\
b^{3/2}\sec^{1/2}x
\end{array}\right),\,v=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a^{1/2}\sin^{1/2}x\\
b^{1/2}\cos^{1/2}x
\end{array}\right),$$which are parallel iff $\tan x=a/b$. Then$$v^2=a\sin x+b\cos x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x-\arctan(a/b))\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2},$$which again is saturated at $\tan x=a/b$. I'll leave you to finish the calculation counting powers of $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Thank you,this is exactly what I want!